# Creating an object on Parse sdk server fail

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to add Parse sdk to my project, and somehow it doesn't add any objects to my app dashboard. I also tried the simple app as I can to check if my existing project has an error but still, same result:

I put Strings to the object, also able get it, but on the dashboard nothing is shown.

(* Please note that i'm testing it with eclipse emulator)

This is the example code:

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "1rOXIAY5a2xeGsIkplFcKxvblNvXGQKLW46xGQmz",
            "FrIN3ugfNhr6iDBXhksUDVzLKfIUd1lvzPAKLVCm");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
    // line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
    Toast.makeText(this, testObject.getString("foo"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Razon Kindly create a new Activity and add the creation of ParseObject code under onCreate.

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        //setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

        //rest of the code
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
        Toast.makeText(this, testObject.getString("foo"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I do. And I usually use parse on few of my projects, my question is other, why on some of the "machines" it works, but on some it actually creates the objects, I can refer/invoke, but it doesn't create a thing in the "site data".

Comment: try to create the class/collection/table and table columns manually on Dashboard and then run your code.